# How to Connect to my localhost project from mobile?

Tags: php, mobile, xampp, localhost

I´m developping a website with mobile version, and I Want to test in my smartphone how The website is behaving in this device. I tried to acess my localhost from my mobile but its not working. Anyone there knwos how I can connect to my localhost project from my mobile?

Comment: Yes..I´m trying with wifi!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by modifying httpd.conf in Apache
you have to set up

find following code and replace From:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
 #onlineoffline tag - don't remove
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 127.0.0.1
 </Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
 #onlineoffline tag - don't remove
 Order Deny,Allow
 #Deny from all
 Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

and turn on WiFi, put the `IP` address in your mobile.
Now Done!

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Pull relevant portions of your link into this answer so the information remains available even if the link breaks.

Comment: Thnaks Code_crash but that from: and to: options are not appear in my httpd.conf :s

Comment: it does not mean from or to. it means you have to change the given default code allow from 127.0.0.1 to allow to all..

Comment: @CesarM I just modify the code. It allow to "c:/wamp/www/" folder from all ip address

Answer (score 2):

Too old question, but I think I have good and simply solution. Let me know by a comment if isn't.

1. Open a terminal and go to project folder
2. Then, execute:
   `php -S 0.0.0.0:9000`

Or to specify where is your index.html:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:9000 -t FOLDER_NAME_WHO_HAVE_INDEX
```

Specifying **0.0.0.0** you allow access to everyone in your network to access to the web project, so be careful.

If you still can't connect and you are under Linux, try to enabling UFW (Linux firewall):

```
sudo ufw enable
```

And allow your smartphone local IP (if you are under Android, go to Wifi settings -> Advanced to obtain your local IP) to access to your local IP from your PC. So, return to CLI and:

```
sudo ufw allow YOUR_SMARTPHONE_LOCAL_IP to any
```

Because allow access to any is not a good practice, remember to disallow the rule when you are done with the tests:

```
sudo ufw deny YOUR_SMARTPHONE_LOCAL_IP to any
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php
you can read the php server manual for more info

Answer (score 1):

If your mobile connected to the same Wifi, then first find out your router external IP address, then forward some port to that localhostIP:portno and finally you'll be able to see that server from your device.

in windows we can forward Ipaddress as below

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=port listenaddress=IP connectport=80 connectaddress=yourlocalhost IP
```